# How to write a Postgres SELECT FOR UPDATE when using the EXCEPT set operator?

Tags: postgresql, select, locking

In Postgres (11, if it matters), I need to do a `SELECT FOR UPDATE` to obtain a collection of rows that I'll subsequently be doing some alterations on, and which I don't want anyone outside my transaction messing with while I do those alterations.

However, the set of rows I want to lock is actually defined by a set-difference, i.e.,

```
SELECT <columns> FROM table1 t1 JOIN table2 t2 ON ... WHERE ...
EXCEPT
SELECT <columns> FROM table1 t1 JOIN table3 t3 ON ... WHERE ...
```

I want the result-set of this set-difference to determine the set of rows that get locked; that is, those rows that are selected by the second `SELECT` should ideally *not* get locked.

But I'm not quite sure where to put the `FOR UPDATE` clause to achieve this. It seems like putting the `FOR UPDATE` immediately after either of the `SELECT` lines above would not give me what I want. And in fact I suspect that I *can't* legally put it after the first of those `SELECT` lines (i.e., just before the `EXCEPT`).

One idea that occurred to me was to parenthesize the second `SELECT` (the one that's the subject of the `EXCEPT`), so that the `FOR UPDATE` won't be interpreted as part of that second `SELECT`:

```
SELECT <columns> FROM table1 t1 JOIN table2 t2 ON ... WHERE ...
EXCEPT
(SELECT <columns> FROM table1 t1 JOIN table3 t3 ON ... WHERE ...)
FOR UPDATE
```

But I'm not sure that that gives me what I want either, even if it turns out to be syntactically acceptable.

It's possible that if I had an idea of the shape of the parse tree for a (Postgres) select statement, I could easily figure this out myself; but as it is, I'm a bit lost right now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot use `FOR UPDATE` together with `UNION`, `INTERSECT` or `EXCEPT`, because this could cause ambiguities in the general case.

I can think of two approaches:

1. Use `EXISTS` and `NOT EXISTS`:

   ```
   SELECT ... FROM table1
   WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM table2 ...
                 WHERE table2.x = table1.x AND ...)
     AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM table3 ...
                     WHERE table3.y = table1.y AND ...)
   FOR UPDATE OF table1;
   ```
2. Use a subquery:

   ```
   SELECT ... FROM table1
   WHERE id IN (SELECT t1.id
                FROM table1 t1 JOIN table2 t2 ON ...
                WHERE ...
                EXCEPT
                SELECT t1.id
                FROM table1 t1 JOIN table3 t3 ON ...
                WHERE ...)
   FOR UPDATE OF table1;
   ```

Comment: Ah, indeed, now I see it, at the end of the section on the [EXCEPT Clause](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/sql-select.html#SQL-EXCEPT): "Currently, FOR NO KEY UPDATE, FOR UPDATE, FOR SHARE and FOR KEY SHARE cannot be specified either for an EXCEPT result or for any input of an EXCEPT." And similarly for the other set-wise operators.Thanks for directing my attention to this.